# Literature.SE is closing - would you like any of our questions?

Tags: discussion, migration

Regrettably, [Literature.SE](http://literature.stackexchange.com) is [closing down](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/) next week due to inactivity.  Consequently, we're looking to move as many questions as we can to new homes, so please consider heading over there, browsing the questions and flagging any that you think might be appropriate for the site here!

Comment: Hmm... how much overlap is there between literature Q&A and Christian doctrine?

Answer (score 3):

Some of the questions in the [`bible`](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible) tag would fit on [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/):

### [Historical books about the Bible](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/705/historical-books-about-the-bible)

Perhaps a bit broad and "pollish", so it might get closed quickly.  But it fits otherwise.

### [In “The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo”, what is the relationship between the numbers and the books in the Bible?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/in-the-girl-with-the-dragon-tattoo-what-is-the-relationship-between-the-numbe)

Focused on the meaning of the novel rather than on the Bible, so it would probably need to be closed on arrival.  But I saw this when it was first asked (I monitor [`bible` questions](http://stackexchange.com/filters/27631/bible) across the network) and thought it could be moved to BH and edited to fit there.

### [Is there a literary source for this instance of quasi-Biblical imagery in Le Carre's third novel?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1238/is-there-a-literary-source-for-this-instance-of-quasi-biblical-imagery-in-le-car)

Doesn't fit as the subject is the novel and the answer seems to be non-Biblical as well.

### [What is the relationship between the Book of Mormon and the Bible?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/495/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-book-of-mormon-and-the-bible)

Maybe a good fit for Christianity?  Probably not for BH, however.

### [How rare/valuable is an 1841 bible?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/235/how-rare-valuable-is-an-1841-bible)

This is a poor fit for StackExchange.

---

The only other [bible](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible) [question][9](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7349/what-order-should-the-books-of-the-protestant-bible-be-read-in) has already been migrated to C.SE.

Comment: The Markdown problem of the last sentence has [already been reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70529/1438).

Comment: Thanks for researching these. I've requested the book of Mormon one be migrated because I think it coudl be covered here, but it comes with a major vote problem. The first one here is really a book recomendation question which we have discouraged in the past. I'm sure Lit was a little diferent on that than other SE sites which generally don't like them.

Answer (score 1):

We've only identified a couple of them so far:

### [What order should the books of the (Protestant) Bible be read in?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/478/what-order-should-the-books-of-the-protestant-bible-be-read-in)

> The Bible is probably one of the most historically significant books for the Western civilization, so it should be a worthwhile read for many a literature geek. In which order should it be read, then? ...

### [Are there different “versions” or “interpretations” of the Koran and (if so) how would a novice choose one?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/955/are-there-different-versions-or-interpretations-of-the-koran-and-if-so-how)

The Koran isn't exactly directly related, but this has some really nice answers (if I may say so) and might be of interests to Christians learning about Islam, as the OP notes..?

> I am a Christian who would like to know more about the Koran, but I don't know where to begin. I do know that there are many, many, many different versions of the Christian Bible, and each of them tends to have a slightly different purpose and/or "slant" (i.e. you can find anything from attempts at literal translations or inter-linear texts or academic translations or paraphrases, etc). ...

---

Please comment here or catch me in chat if you would like to see these migrated over!

Comment: The first one I already flagged for migration. The second one I'm pretty sure we don't want, but thanks.